# I'm writing a HTTP server, what functionalities should I add to it?

Tags: python, http, httpserver

I know this isn't a SO favored question, but I didn't get enough info I want through Googling.
So basiclly I'm writing a HTTP server as a class project. I'm NOT asking how to do it. What I want to know is: **what are the basic functionalities to add?**

So far I've got:

1. returning requested pages/resources
2. adding `Date`,`Content-Type`,`Server`,`Content-Length` headers
3. a simple cache machanism, adding requested page to memory so that next time it's requested I can get it from memory.

I'm using Python [gevent](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gevent.org%2F&ei=y8lAU7fiHMejkgW11IHQDg&usg=AFQjCNFYjV95giLG8Qaz_cJTdQXtgEvtyQ&sig2=x9KHRe1jmMVDLUxJro_1ww&cad=rjt) to handle requests, basically it's an asynchronous lib. When I receive a request, I spawn a new greenlet to handle it.

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you writing another HTTP server? Take Tornado, it uses gevent and achieves blazing-fast performance. Take gevent.pywsgi, it's a full-featured standard HTTP server. Unless you're doing it for an educational purpose, spare yourself time to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Does it need to support both http/1.0 and http/1.1 ?  http/1.1 has some Connection header semantics you need to be wary of.  If you can get away with using tornado.web or something similar, you should prefer that.

Comment: @9000 There's no point in writing anthoer HTTP server, but there is in learing to write it.

Comment: @laike9m: OK, than it's the educational purpose I thought about. If so, it's indeed a good project. You still can take a look at existing implementations when you have finished yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just a full implementation of HTTP 1.1 with proper error handling is non-trivial.

[image: HTTP flowchart]

The flowchart starts:

- Is service available? Status 503 if not.
- Is URI too long? Status 414 if it is.
- Are headers too large? Status 431 if it is.
- Does the request require any functionality that is unimplemented? Status 501 if there is.
- etc…